# is there any comptability of android studio 1.5.1 and retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I am facing below error while adding retrofit library in android studio 1.5.1.

Error:(8, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'
Possible causes:The project 'RetrofitMy Application' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

I googled in order to resolve above issue but did not find yet ,any one can help me

Answer (score 0):

You should change your

```
implementation 'thelibrary:1.0.0'
```

to

```
compile 'thelibrary:1.0.0'
```

Comment: where i need to change it ??

Comment: in build.gradle- app module

Comment: not working     compile 'thelibrary:1.0.0'

Comment: No, it was given to you as an example. Here you will replace the starting part of the power-up dependency with "compile".